Selecting Checkbox values based on JSON Array
I am storing some id values as json strings in my database. I am using these same ids as the checkbox values in my Bootstrap multiselect checkbox control on my form.
[{"formLookupId":16},{"formLookupId":23},{"formLookupId":17}]

My approach is to set a hiddenField value with this array, and then use JS to set the checkbox selected values appropriately (since I cannot do this on the server-side as they are not server controls).
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFormchkboxes" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

I am close with this approach, but I am not sure what I am missing here in terms of the javascript. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?  I don't have a lot of experience with json arrays in JS and my JS code is not passing the values.includes(parseInt(checkbox.value)) test. Also, if there is a better way to do this that is more efficient that doesn't involve making my controls server-side controls,but allows me to manipulate these checkboxes server-side, I am open to that.
HTML sample checkbox control:
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="16"> FooBar Checkbox </label>

JS:
 if ($('#hdnFormchkboxes').attr('value') != null && $('#hdnFormchkboxes').attr('value') != '') {
            var hdnFormcheckedvals = $('#hdnFormchkboxes').attr('value');
            var values = JSON.parse(hdnFormcheckedvals);

            var container = document.querySelector('.ddlchkProfessionCheckboxes');
            const checkboxes = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');               

            checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
                if (values.includes(parseInt(checkbox.value))) {
                    checkbox.checked = true;
                }
            });
        }

UPDATE: I am able to set the checkboxes as checked using Barmar's suggestion in parsing the json data.
var values = JSON.parse(hdnFormcheckedvals).map(el => el.formLookupId);

            var container = document.querySelector('.ddlchkProfessionCheckboxes');
            const checkboxes = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

            checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
                if (values.includes(parseInt(checkbox.value))) {
                    checkbox.checked = true;                 
                }
            });

            $('#ddlListBox').multiselect('rebuild');

I was also able to set the label for the selected checkboxes that were set w JQuery by forcing a change event on the checkbox after selecting it.
$(checkbox).trigger('change');

My issue now is that I would like to force the change event for the EventListener I have already created at $(document).ready as I would like to collect the checked checkboxes to repeat the selected checkboxes logic for the child list I have that collects options based on what was selected in this parent list. My change event doesn't seem to be hitting that change event.
var container = document.querySelector('.ddlchkProfessionCheckboxes');

        var checkboxesAll = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

        checkboxesAll.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                const rwSeries = document.getElementById("rwddlSeries");
                rwSeries.hidden = false;
                var container = document.querySelector('.ddlchkProfessionCheckboxes');
                var checkboxesAllchked = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

                const formIds = [];
                debugger;
                for (var i = 0, len = checkboxesAllchked.length; i < len; i++) {

                    formIds.push(checkboxesAllchked[i].value);
                    /*RdMessageVersionNums.push({ "hdnMessageVer": versionNum[i].value });*/

                }
                $jq.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Messages.aspx/GetSeriesforFormIds',
                    data: "{'data':'" + JSON.stringify(formIds) + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //debugger;
                        if (data.d != null) {
                            const rwSeries = document.getElementById("rwddlSeries");
                            rwSeries.hidden = false;

                            var $checkboxContainer = $('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes .multiselect-container');
                            $checkboxContainer.html("");
                           
                            var temp = data.d;

                            if (temp != '') {

                                //debugger;
                                var obj = $.parseJSON(temp);

                                //debugger;
                                var $container = $('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes select');
                                $container.html("");
                                if ((obj != '') && (obj.data.length > 0)) {
                                    for (i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
                                        $container.append('<option value="' + obj.data[i].Id + '">' + obj.data[i].text + '</option>')
                                        $checkboxContainer.append('<li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="' + obj.data[i].Id + '">' + obj.data[i].text + '</label ></a ></li >')
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        
                        //debugger;
                        $('#ddlListBox').multiselect('rebuild');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                });


values is an array of objects, you need to extract the formLookupId properties from them.
var values = JSON.parse(hdnFormcheckedvals).map(el => el.formLookupId);


This works, thank you! But it’s not working in setting the selected items count on the label for the bootstrap multiselect() functionality. I’m left wondering how I can check these checkboxes using jquery and still have that functionality for the control.

How are you turning the checkboxes into a multi-select? If bootstrap is doing that, there's probably a method you need to call to sync it with the checkboxes.

I updated my question with your solution as that was helpful. I am trying now to simply force the checkbox to fire the change event I created in my event listener so the ajax call can be make to populate a child list that will appear after this one so I can then populate the values of that additional list.
